# Load Javascript after page content is loaded with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I am using Ajax (and jQuery, and also CoffeeScript) to load pages in a new web-site I am creating. For the navigation menu I then use the jQuery function [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load only one part of the page (namely, the content) like this (from `/page1`):

```js
$( 'a' ).click ->
  $( '#container' ).load '/page2 #content'

  false
```

The problem with this is that I have JavaScript code in `page1` (or, more correctly, in a template file) that is global on the site (due to the asset pipeline as I am using Rails 3.1). This code binds some actions to events (is this the correct jargon?) in DOM elements that are located in `page2`. But, as this script is run in the page that is first loaded (which easily could be `page1`), then the script that binds these actions to the elements will be executed in `page1`, and thus the DOM elements that they actually *should* be bound to (in `page2`) will not be touched.

Now, I know some ways I can fix this, but I don't like neither of them. One of these would be to put this action/event binding into a function, and then call this method after loading `page2` with Ajax, but this would require me to either have introduce a special case in my page loading logic where I load the binding function after page load to bind the elements, or to have a script in the `page2` content where I call the function.

I would rather not go with the former approach, as I have a more general way of loading pages (by using the `<a>` tag's `href` attribute), and introducing special cases on page load just uglifies it all. The latter solution is a rather nicer one I believe, but I would hate to put `<script>`tags into the content of the page that I am retrieving. I like separating content from behaviour and all that, and I feel that this might be mixing it all up a bit.

So, what I really want to know here is whatever would be a good way to solve this problem. If anyone out there knows how to go about doing this, then I would welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into jQuery's [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event binding.

Events bound with `live()` are applied to retrospectively added DOM elements as well, which should solve your problem.

**Edit:** To be precise, `live()` binds to `$(document)` and checks the `target` attribute of events that have bubbled all the way up through the DOM – that's why the binding works even when elements are added after binding the event callback.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="some_triggers">
    <a id="foo" href="#">Foo!</a>
</div>
```

Example jQuery:

```
$('#foo').click(function(){ alert('foo') });
$('#bar').click(function(){ alert('bar') });
$('#some_triggers').append('<a id="bar" href="#">Bar!</a>');
$('#foo').live('click', function(){ alert('foo live()!') });
$('#bar').live('click', function(){ alert('bar live()!') });

// -> clicking #foo alerts "foo" and "foo live()"
// -> clicking #bar alerts "bar live()" only, since the '.click()' binding doesn't work on non-existent DOM elements.
```

Comment: Wow, just read through the documentation, and it seems exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you very much, I'll look into it right away and check back to say if it works or not. :-)